# Curry/Uncurry monad transformer lifting

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm writing some `lift` functions that take a record field function, some parameters and then `lift` the action stored in the record to another `Monad` where I'm working in:

```
liftCapability :: Has capability e
                => ( capability -> IO a )
                -> ReaderT e IO a
liftCapability f = do
  capability <- asks getter
  lift $ f capability
```

The problem is that I've arrived to a place where I have lots of those `lift` functions each for a different arity if I need to call it with more parameters:

```
liftCapability1 :: Has capability e
                => ( capability -> a -> IO b )
                -> a
                -> ReaderT e IO b
liftCapability1 f a = do
  capability <- asks getter
  lift $ f capability a


liftCapability2 :: Has capability e
                => ( capability -> a -> b -> IO c )
                -> a
                -> b
                -> ReaderT e IO c
liftCapability2 f a b = do
  capability <- asks getter
  lift $ f capability a b
```

Is there a way to abstract the application of the last arguments of the function that worked as an eta-reduce?

So far I've tried using `curryN` and `uncurryN` from the [tuple package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Curry.html), but this doesn't work, as it cannot curry less than two arguments:

```
liftC f =
  liftC' f . curryN
 where
  liftC' f a = do
    c <- asks getter
    lift $ (f c) (uncurryN a)
```

Is this possible, or I am doomed to have a function per arity?

Comment: Note that if `capability` was the _last_ argument to `f`, instead of the first one, the problem would be much simpler. I'd only implement `liftCapability` and let the users write `liftCapability (\x -> f x a b)` instead of `liftCapability2 f a b`, since the former is not that bad, and trivially generalizes to any number of arguments.

Comment: Yeah, definitely is not that bad, and given that `liftCapability` won't be used that much over all the project, it is a great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to change the order of arguments on the functions you're using `liftCapability` for.

```
λ :t \f b -> liftCapability $ \x -> f x b
\f b -> liftCapability $ \x -> f x b                        
  :: Has t1 e => (t1 -> t2 -> IO a) -> t2 -> ReaderT e IO a 
λ :t \f c b -> liftCapability $ \x -> f x c b
\f c b -> liftCapability $ \x -> f x c b                           
  :: Has t1 e =>                                                   
     (t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> IO a) -> t2 -> t3 -> ReaderT e IO a
```

Another is to use a typeclass

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}
-- ...
class LiftableCapability v where
   type Low v :: *
   type Env v :: *
   liftCapability :: Has capability (Env v) => (capability -> Low v) -> v

instance LiftableCapability (ReaderT e IO a) where
   type Low (ReaderT e IO a) = IO a
   type Env (ReaderT e IO a) = e
   liftCapability f = lift . f =<< asks getter

instance LiftableCapability v => LiftableCapability (a -> v) where
   type Low (a -> v) = a -> Low v
   type Env (a -> v) = Env v
   liftCapability f = liftCapability . flip f
```